# I want to populate a PIE chart when I mouseover a textbox. How can I do it with PRIMEFACES?

Tags: java, user-interface, primefaces, tooltip, pie-chart

I have 2 columns in my webpage which has some value like this.
[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7pcE.png)

My requirement:
When I will mouseover on "Value" column of "RowNumber"=1, a pie chart will populate and will show the percentages of "rownumber" columns.
I have to do it in PrimeFaces.
I have done it in below way, but while mouseover piechart is not populating.

Comment: Please have a look at your question again and edit it

Comment: I want to populate a piechart dynamically, whenever I mouseover an inputtext field.

Comment: Please have a look at your question again and edit it. Don't you miss anything